# Which of these methods is a correct way to return in python?

Tags: python

I have two functions which do the same thing basically but return differently in case of exceptions. Which one is the preferred approach?

Approach 1:

```
def f1():
    try:
        data = some_random_function()
        return data["success"]
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return "failure"
```

Approach 2:

```
def f2():
    try:
        data = some_random_function()
        return data["success"]
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    return "failure"
```

Comment: Assuming Approach 2 has a typo and the `print` and `return` are supposed to be in `f2`, then there is no difference at all. The only way your code can get past the `success` return is if there is an exception so whether your `failure` return is inside that expcetion, or after it, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both the approaches work the same way i.e. `return data["success"]` in case of an exception-free code and `return "failure"` otherwise, the two approaches differ in the way they convey the information :

*A1*- Return "failure" in case of an exception

*A2*- Return "failure" as a default return value.

So, it's my suggestion that you use the second approach as it is more clear and explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Although both approaches are equivalent, I would recommend approach 1.  It makes much clearer that 'failure' is returned only when there is an exception.  Someone reading approach 2 may get a first impression that it always returns 'failure'.  This is strictly from a clean code perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a generic catch-all for errors, both approaches are equivalent, because in case of an exception you'll enter the `print "failure"` branch.

I guess it comes down to matter of taste and maybe future maintainability, i.e. when you add more `except` branches to handle some errors differently, to choose approach 2.

Answer (score 1):

Its all down to personal preferences. For me, approach 1 is much clearer than two but both are good solutions. I think its more than just individual preference, its more of the code base you are working with. If you are working with a team, look into code with similar structure, see what other's have done. A uniform codebase is much valuable than fancy code here and there.

Also, for languages like `JavaScript` and `python`, which have functional scope, I want to put forward a third option:

```
def f3():
    try:
        data = some_random_function()
        message = "success"
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        message = "failure"
    return message
```